# Retaining changed data on table pagination - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pagination, smart-table

I have a requirement to submit changes made in my angularjs table. This table is populated asynchronously and so the pagination is dynamic.

Whenever I make a change in a page(*eg: page 1*) and move on to any other page(*eg: page 2*), the data changed in the page 1 is getting reset on accessing the again. The changed data is not maintained as such.

Worked on to see that, there could be few ways to avoid this.

1. Restricting the use of st-safe-src in table definition. (But this
   option was possible only to synchronous table loading. The table is
   not getting populated if I remove the safe source)
2. Use a variable to store/retrieve state of dynamic form controls like
   this example, which had an ajax call and populated the entire input
   tags based on ajax validations, which too didn't work since the
   default value of my select option is be based on the DB input.

Is there a possible way to do this in angularjs?

**My table**:

```
<table id="recordTable" st-table="display_record_returns"  st-safe-src="recordReturns" ng-show="recordReturns"
   class="table table-bordered table-striped shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" ng-controller="BotRulesController">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
         <th style="white-space: nowrap">CASE NO</th>
         <th st-sort="code">MATCH CODE</th>
         <th st-sort="decision">RULE</th>
         <th st-sort="email">EMAIL</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr id="row.code" valign="middle" st-select-row="row"
         st-select-mode="multiple"
         ng-repeat="row in display_record_returns track by row.code"
         ng-attr-id="{{::row.code}}">
         <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
         <td align="left" ng-bind="row.code"></td>
         <td>
            <select id="ruleChangeSelect_{{row.code}}" ng-change="ruleChanged(row.code, row.decision, selectionModel[row.code])" class="custom-select"
               style="margin-left: 0px"
               ng-model="selectionModel[row.code]"
               ng-options="choice.name for choice in possibleOptions track by choice.id">
               <option value="" hidden="hidden" readonly="" ng-hide="true"></option>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td ng-bind="row.email"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
      <tr style="font-size:0.8rem !important;">
         <td colspan="22" class="text-center">
            <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="5"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

**My js**:

```
$scope.getRules = function () {

    $http({
        'url': '/getRules',
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.recordReturns = response.data;
        $scope.ruleOptions = [{
            decision: "A"
        }, {
            decision: "B"
        }, {
            decision: "C"
        }];

        $scope.possibleOptions = getUniqueValues($scope.ruleOptions, 'decision')
            .map(function (id) {
                return {
                    id: id,
                    name: id
                }
            });

        $scope.selectionModel = {};

        angular.forEach($scope.recordReturns, function (input) {
            $scope.selectionModel[input.code] = $scope.possibleOptions.filter(function (opt) {
                return opt.id === input.decision;
            })[0];
        });

        function getUniqueValues(array, prop) {
            return [...new Set(array.map(item => item[prop]))];
        }

        $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    })
};
```

Comment: try to copy display_record_returns = angular.copy(recordReturns) on page change. If you edit value in a table add some buttons like save or cancel to update both collection values.

Comment: Hi Ghanzanfar. Thanks for your answer. Can you please provide a documentation link to know about smart-table pagination changes? I can see the same, only for data tables.

Comment: Please read this doc carefully
http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

Comment: Hi Ghazanfar. I am new to smart-table. Can you please help in guiding through a fiddle or a small code sample? I have added `st-page-change="rememberCurrentPage(recordReturns)"` on page change and the method is getting called. I'm making a copy as you suggested. But this is not working as expected.

Comment: And I am also unclear about the class. Please correct me if I'm wrong. `angular.copy` copies and keeps hold of the data we specify but not the class in which the data is wrapped.

Comment: I checked it by running a sample to update value in a row and watch both rowCollection and displayedCollection both values got updated so it is difficult to retain the values in paging. In this case you have to create custom directive for inline editing and provide save and cancel button and when on save click update binding values. Also I also want you to try modal boxe edit option to update all field in a modal.

Comment: See here http://jsfiddle.net/7qLr65wj/